# SwiftUI removing a space on the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, swiftui

on may SwiftUI view i'm try to display a simple TOP blue bar, a red rectangle  and a lower bar, as you can see from the attached picture there is a strange white space from the topper and red rectangle on the top part that I want to remove but I don't understand why is there.

[image: SwiftUi]

here is the simple code:

```
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                //upper top bar
                HStack{
                    Text("TOP BAR")

                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/10)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("BlueW"), Color("DARK")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing).shadow(radius: 2)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROBLEM HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                // testing rectangle
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)

                //lower bar
                ZStack {

                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(20)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: 75)
                            .foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" ? .black : .gray)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.viewRouter.currentView = "home"
                        }
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                            Button(action: {
                                self.isAddPresented = true
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.showPopUp ? 90 : 0))
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isAddPresented) {
                                AirportView(dm: self.dm, airport: self.general.airportData, dismissFlag: self.$isAddPresented)

                            }
                        }

                        .offset(y: -geometry.size.height/10/2)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.showPopUp.toggle()
                            }

                        }
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(20)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: 75)
                            .foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "routekit" ? .black : .gray)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.viewRouter.currentView = "routekit"
                        }

                    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/10)
                        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("BlueW"), Color("DARK")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing).shadow(radius: 2))
                }
            }

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies within the `HStack` having its edges ignoring all safe area (`.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`).

[image]

As you can see, if you inspect your view, your green view (`HStack`) is actually inside the `GeometryReader`, but its frame goes outside.

Solution: remove `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`.

**New problem** though, there would be a white space at the top safe area.

Solution:

Set `GeometryReader` to `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])`

Voila!

[image]